# Using CookieAuthentication plus custom scheme in Asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication

So far my project uses Cookie authentication with a call like

```
 services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(
                options =>
                {
                    options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    };
                    options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context =>
                    {
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name))
                            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                        else
                            context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    };
                })
            ;
```

I would like to extend this so I can use BasicAuth as an alternative to Cookies.

So I changed the above to

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler>("BasicAuthentication",
                options => { })
            .AddCookie(
                options =>
                {
                    options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
                    {
                        //when defaultScheme is CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, I come here when using BasicAuth
                        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    };
                    options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context =>
                    {
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name))
                            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                        else
                            context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    };
                })
            ;
```

with

```
public class BasicAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{

    public BasicAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.NoResult());
        }

        Response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic");

        // Get authorization key
        var authorizationHeader = Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();
        var authHeaderRegex = new Regex(@"Basic (.*)");

        if (!authHeaderRegex.IsMatch(authorizationHeader))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Authorization code not formatted properly."));
        }

        var authBase64 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authHeaderRegex.Replace(authorizationHeader, "$1")));
        var authSplit = authBase64.Split(Convert.ToChar(":"), 2);
        var authUsername = authSplit[0];
        var authPassword = authSplit.Length > 1 ? authSplit[1] : throw new Exception("Unable to get password");

        if (authUsername != "myuser" || authPassword != "mypass")
        {
            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("The username or password is not correct."));
        }        

        var claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "crocoll") };
        foreach (var role in new List<string>{"ProjectManager"})
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        }
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name)));
    }
}
```

but unfortunately my Handler's HandleAuthenticateAsync method does not get called as long as I have `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` as default scheme.

But changing default scheme to "BasicAuthentication" makes CookieAuthentication stop working.

What can I do to make both work in parallel?

Comment: when you support multiple schemes, it must be made clear on which scheme is used for each request. But from your question, I don't understand that point, when this scheme is used but not the other?

Comment: maybe that's my issue, I thought that could be detected for each request (by the request headers/cookies). So you are saying I need different endpoints for different auth schemes? I was hoping I could reuse my existing Controller methods/endpoints?

Comment: Ok, thanks to @KingKing's comment I understood I need to specify both schemes in the AuthenticationSchemes property of the `[Authorize]` attribute of my Controller method